# How to turn off the auto-complete of Intellisense on VS Code when coding '(' after function

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I use VS Code, and I'm writing JavaScript.

I want to turn off auto-complete, when I'm writing a function. Intellisense suggests some
candidates while I write  a new function.

And, I finish writing function name and input '(' Key, Intellisense replaces my function name with the top of the list of candidates automatically.
But I don't want to write new function. I don't want  my code replaced when I push '(' Key.
(Of course, I haven't push Enter or Tab key or other keys then.)

[image]

I have already tried turn off the suggestion.

```
”editor.quickSuggestions”:  false
```

But this option doesn't suits for me.
I use suggestions and auto-complete.

Please tell me what setting is suitable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows/Linux - `Ctrl + Shift + P`

On MacOS - `Cmd + Shift + P`

In the search box type `settings.json`

paste the following line there

```
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false
```

[image]

Comment: I had 3 json settings files, the correct one I needed to modify was at this file path: C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json